# Open iWatch Application from iPhone Click event

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, apple-watch, watchconnectivity

I have searched on stacks , I found only way iPhone application from iWatch Application click event, but I didn't find any way for open iWatch Application when iPhone app event call.

From iWatch to open iPhone  app used this code , Its working fine ,

```
WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication(randomColorComponents,
  reply: { [unowned self](reply, error) -> Void in})
```

Please suggest how's to possible open iWatch application from iPhone

I have also update iWatch OS in 2.2 but still awaiting for this feature

Comment: i got same issue. please guide for right path for done task.:)

Comment: You can't bring an app to the foreground on the Apppe Watch from the paired phone. The user needs to either launch the app from a notification or the app icon on the watch or a glance

Comment: @Paulw11 , How to possible open via Notification , can you suggest

Comment: If the user taps on the notification it will launch the watch app. However, iOS determines whether a notification is displayed on the phone or the watch based on user activity.  You cannot route a notification directly to the watch